# How to display item photo in atom feed?

Tags: xml, rss, feed, atom-feed

I want to display a photo for each item in atom feed. I used this structure for my entry

```
<entry>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link href="http://page" />
    <id>http://page</id>
    <updated>DATE</updated>
    <summary>DESCRIPTION</summary>
    <content type="image/jpg" 
    src="http://image" />
</entry>
```

but when adding the feed in Google Reader, it will not display images. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Does it have to be Atom? RSS can do this easily.

Comment: No, I did choose atom, as it is more advanced than RSS. What is your suggestion for RSS structure?

Comment: I just realized the problem and posted a solution. I had tried my 'working rss' and it wasn't working. Forgot about the way Google Reader reads feeds...read the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Atom or RSS you need to enable hotlinking to your files for Google Reader to read them, as decribed at:

[**“HowTo: Allow Google Reader Access To Hotlink-Protected Images”**

<sup>By JP Habaradas on April 27, 2009</sup>](http://jaypeeonline.net/tips-tricks/howto-allow-google-reader-access-to-hotlink-protected-images/)

Also, you may want to link this question to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as you will need to make .htaccess modification and have Apache Rewrites enabled and configured.

Comment: I love that someone downvoted an accepted answer without any comment as to what is wrong with the accepted solution.