# Adding Images or Thumbnails to Atom 1.0 Entries

Tags: image, feed, yahoo-api, atom-feed, google-base

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110481/displaying-images-in-atom-feed) StackOverflow answer suggests that you should use HTML entry content and use a standard `<img>` tag to link to your images.

```html
<content type="html">
  <![CDATA[
    <a href="http://test.lvh.me:3000/listings/341-test-pics?locale=en">
      <img alt="test_pic" src="http://test.lvh.me:3000/system/images/20/medium/test_pic.jpg?1343246102" />
    </a>
  ]]>
</content>
```

I have also found something called the Yahoo media extensions [here](http://www.sciencemedianetwork.org/wiki/Enclosures_in_yahoo_media,_rss,_and_atom) which allows you to add custom additional elements.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<!-- ommitted -->
  <entry>
    <!-- ommitted -->
    <media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" url="path_to_image.jpg" />
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Google also seems to have its own similar extensions. See [here](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160593?hl=en).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<!-- ommitted -->
  <entry>
    <!-- ommitted -->
    <g:image_link>http://www.google.com/images/google_sm.gif</g:image_link>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

My own intuition tells me I should simply be able to add links to images like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <!-- ommitted -->
  <entry>
    <!-- ommitted -->
    <link rel="enclosure" type="image/png" length="1337"
        href="http://example.org/image.png"/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

What is the correct approach for maximum compatibility?

Comment: I can't believe a major piece of internet infrastructure like Atom 1.0 that is 8 years old, has so little documentation. There aren't even many blog posts about it!!!

Comment: I've written a blog post (one of the few written in the last few years about the subject that I could find) [here](http://rehansaeed.com/building-rssatom-feeds-for-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to do what Wordpress RSS 2.0 feeds do — if you want your post image to appear in feedly for example, put the `<p><img...></p>` at the top of the content. My eleventy setup has post header image inside article, but outside `content` variable's contents which are used in the feed. I solve the problem adding the image back:

```xml
<item>
...
  <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[<p>{% include "src/components/partials/post-hero-img.njk" %}</p>{{ post.templateContent | textDeletePresentationDivs | htmlToAbsoluteUrls(absolutePostUrl) | safe }}]]>
  </content:encoded>
```

[source in git](https://gitlab.com/codsen/codsen.com/-/blob/master/src/feed.njk)

I checked, neither Atom nor RSS 2.0 feeds have post images set anywhere as standalone tags. They're simply at the top of the article's content.

With regards to your examples...

The "vanilla" Atom RSS feed has a schema `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` and its documentation is defined in [RFC4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287).

According to it, "vanilla" Atom RSS feed strictly can have `<logo>` which is the 2:1 ratio image, the [logo of the feed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.8). Sadly, it is placed *in the root* of XML (notice `atom:logo` in the spec, it's not `atom:entry:logo`). Practically, this means, you can put a picture of your RSS feed itself, but not per-article. If you do put `<logo>` inside `<entry>`, the feed won't pass the validators and post image won't appear in feedly (I tried).

Also, spec defines `<icon>` which is vaguely [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.5) as a small, square image, also placed in the root. Feedly seem to detect the website's favicon anyway, although it doesn't hurt to set this tag up in rss explicitly.

That's all there is — Atom spec doesn't officially define a way how to put images per-article.

Here's where additional namespaces come in (or RSS 2.0, different spec, different XML). You mentioned `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"` in example. I tried it, post images won't show in feedly. Plus, spec link `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` is not showing any specs.

Google namespace you quoted, `xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"` also doesn't work, post images don't show up in feedly.

The `link` approach, `<link rel="enclosure" type="image/png" length="1337" href="http://example.org/image.png"/>` would be promising except `length` is meant to state the [filesize in bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_enclosure#Syntax). In [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev/) that's problematic value to get, for example.

To sum up, the best practice is put post header image at the top of the content, inside `<content>`.